# Why is an adiabat steeper than an isotherm in a $p$-$V$ curve?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume, adiabatic

What I have so far gathered is a mathematical explanation.

Since for an adiabatic process, $pV^γ=$ constant, for a unit change in pressure, change in volume would be very less. Therefore, if compared to an isothermal process, the adiabat will be steeper.

But what is the theoretical explanation for this? And why does these conditions reverse in the case of compression? I believe the "PV^γ=K" equation won't work there, or would it?

Ps. I'm considering the same starting points for each type of process. (P1,V1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is an adiabatic steeper than an isotherm in a $p$-$V$ curve?

The slope is steeper for the adiabatic process because there is no heat and all the work done in expansion is at the expense of internal energy. That means the temperature drops during expansion whereas it does not for the isothermal expansion where heat provides the energy for expansion. For one mole of an ideal gas

$$P=\frac {RT}{V}$$

In the adiabatic process when $V$ increases $T$ decreases, whereas the temperature is constant for the isothermal process. That means for a given volume increase, the pressure drop in the adiabatic process is greater than the isothermal process, which makes the curve steeper for the adiabatic process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. How would the same explanation be appropriate for compression?

Comment: For the adiabatic compression when the volume decreases the temperature increases whereas for the isothermal compression the temperature is constant. Thus for the same decrease in volume there is a greater increase in pressure for the adiabatic compression, again resulting in a steeper curve.

Answer (score 0):

That is very much wrong.

We can plot the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wqkmxsave0) in desmos considering x axis as Volume and y axis as Pressure.

Black is Adiabatic curve, Green is Isothermal curve.

We can clearly see that although the slope of green was steeper initially, after a particular point, black becomes more steeper and even more after that, when $p,v \to \infty$, the slopes would be rather same

[image: graph]

This curve is take for a general isotherm and a adiabat for a triatomic molecule.

Comment: No, it's not. The black one is adiabatic and the green one is isothermal.

Comment: @StutiGupta, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I mentioned same starting points for each process, though. I believe that is the not the graph we'll get, if this fact is taken into consideration.

Comment: @Mel, I have attached the entire graph, both of which are hyperbolic in nature. From here on, you should be able to do it yourself. The intersection of the curves gives the point where both the curves have the same starting point

Comment: @DevNotTaken oh, right. i'm sorry if this sounds repetitive - but i still don't get what you're trying to say. could you be a bit more elaborative? in my defence, i'm a high-schooler fresh after learning this topic.

Comment: @Mel You can consider the intersection of the two curves as your starting point for expansion moving to the right and the starting point for compression moving to the left. In both directions the adiabatic is steeper than the isothermal as I indicated to you for the reasons described in my answer